# Seeking immigration record John Redonnett, born in France, who came to US ca 1840s?

Tags: united-states, immigration, 1840s, france, maine

John Redonnett appears to have come to the US circa the 1840s but can you suggest where I could look for more information?

Two records indicate that he was born in France.

- He is in the 1850 US Census which suggests that he was born in 1822:

> "United States Census, 1850," database with images, FamilySearch
>   (familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M6J1-PTK : 9 November 2014), John
>   Redonnett, Bristol, Lincoln, Maine, United States; citing family 525,
>   NARA microfilm publication M432 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives
>   and Records Administration, n.d.).

- His [tombstone in Maine](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=64290073) reads that he was born in Toulouse, France in 1826.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Are you perhaps trying to find an immigration record to the US for John?  Or do you have that and are seeking to find a record of his life in France before that?  Either way there is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to provide more details to make your question into something that we can try to help with.

Comment: Is this the John Redonnett that you are interested in?  "United States Census, 1850," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M6J1-PTK : 9 November 2014), John Redonnett, Bristol, Lincoln, Maine, United States; citing family 525, NARA microfilm publication M432 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.).

Comment: Yes, this is the John Redonnett I am looking for. His tombstone in Maine reads that he was born in Toulouse, France in 1826. Here the census suggests that he was born in 1822.

Comment: Jean-Claude, would you mind clarifying precisely what information you are trying to find? I suggest you collect together every piece of information you know about him. Any one document or source may be inaccurate or incorrect, but by analysing a number of sources you can get a better idea of, for example, when and where someone might have been born. You will then be better able to direct your searches.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it with additional details at any time.  Are you perhaps trying to find an immigration record to the US for John? Or do you have that and are seeking to find a record of his life in France before that?  Or is it something else that you want to ask?

Comment: Actually, I am going to take a punt and assume that you are looking for an immigration record, and edit your question to say that.

Comment: I've edited the question because you asked for "a document to prove" what he was asking about.  A single document is not proof.  You can find more information on the skillbuilding section of the website of the Board for Certification of Genealogists. Here is their page on the Genealogical Proof Standard: http://www.bcgcertification.org/resources/standard.html  You may also want to consult their publication Genealogy Standards http://www.bcgcertification.org/catalog/index.html or Dr. Tom Jones' Mastering Genealogical Proof from NGS: http://www.ngsgenealogy.org/cs/mastering_genealogical_proof

Answer (score 3):

This [Maine, Veterans Cemetery Records, 1676-1918](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33S7-91WX-35H?i=3574&wc=M6G9-QTL%3A264118001%2C264380801%3Fcc%3D1985567&cc=1985567) seems to confirm what you have concerning place of birth, and includes the fact that John Redonnett was a Civil War veteran, as well as cause of death.[image]

As to immigration the first census does list John as a Sailor, so he may have arrived as crew and not passenger. Some Redonet names do appear ([Louisiana, New Orleans Passenger Lists, 1820-1945](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bsurname%3Aredonnett~%20%2Bbirth_place%3Afrance~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1800-1840~%20%2Bresidence_place%3A%22bristol%20maine%22~&collection_id=1916009)) entering through New Orleans from France, so that may be the area to focus on.

There are also some birth records ([France, Haute-Garonne, Toulouse, Civil Registration, 1792-1893](https://familysearch.org/search/record/results?count=20&query=%2Bsurname%3Aredonnett~%20%2Bbirth_place%3Afrance~%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1800-1840~%20%2Bresidence_place%3A%22bristol%20maine%22~&collection_id=2358735)) from France which may eventually provide a connection.